# Highcharts on click show larger graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm setting up a way to be able to enlarge small-ish charts on my webpage by un-hiding a page 'overlay' div and creating a secondary, larger chart inside it with the same data as the chart which was clicked on.

```
function DrawSmallChart() {

chart_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

LargeChartOptions = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        data: chart_data
    }],
};

SmallChartOptions = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        data: chart_data
    }],
    events: {
        click = function (e) { DrawLargeChart(LargeChartOptions); }
    }
};

$('#smallchart-div-container').highcharts(SmallChartOptions);
}

function DrawLargeChart(options) {

chart_container_div = document.getElementById("graph-div-id");
chart_container_div.style.display = ""
$('#graph-div-id').off();
$("#graph-overlay-graph").highcharts('StockChart', options);

}
```

I have another function that hides this div when I click a button.

The first time I click the small graph when the page loads, the big graph shows up fine with all the data. The second time I click it, the graph shows but with no data.

I've used the debugger to flick through what is happening and I've found exactly what the problem is, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

The first time I click the graph, the `DrawLargeChart` function is called with `options.series = <Array containing my series object with chart_data>`. The second time, `DrawLargeChart` is called with `options.series = null`.

When I refresh the page it is the same - first click works, subsequent clicks don't. I suspect it has something to do with the `chart_data` variable...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

## EDIT 1:

After some more debugging, it is clear that the `options` object which is passed to `DrawLargeChart()` is not the same in the first click versus subsequent clicks. There is nothing in my code which is changing the `LargeChartOptions` structure

## EDIT 2:

I figured out that this is a pass by value / pass by reference error. `LargeChartOptions` is being passed in by reference which no longer exists after the first click. Is there a way to pass it by value? I'd rather not have to type out the `LargeChartOptions` (much bigger than I've typed up here) into the function parameter in case I change anything in future

## EDIT 3 // I've figured it out:

I figured out what the problem is. The `$(target).highcharts(options)` function actually *modifies* the options object and sets `options.series = null`

## The solution

I modified the `DrawLargeChart` function to create a local copy of `options` by using `options_buffer = $.extend(true,{},options);`

```
function DrawLargeChart(options) {

chart_container_div = document.getElementById("graph-div-id");
options_buffer = $(target).highcharts(options);
chart_container_div.style.display = ""
$('#graph-div-id').off();
$("#graph-overlay-graph").highcharts('StockChart', options_buffer);

}
```

By creating `options_buffer`, the highcharts function cannot modify `LargeChartOptions` (because `options` is just a reference to that variable - yay Javascript)

Comment: Have you any live demo of your chart? Can you recreate it on the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It's probably a matter of scope.  Try defining your data and options variables outside of any functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer (in original post but copied here):

I modified the `DrawLargeChart` function to create a local copy of options by using `options_buffer = $.extend(true,{},options);`

```
function DrawLargeChart(options) {

chart_container_div = document.getElementById("graph-div-id");
options_buffer = $(target).highcharts(options);
chart_container_div.style.display = ""
$('#graph-div-id').off();
$("#graph-overlay-graph").highcharts('StockChart', options_buffer);

}
```

By creating `options_buffer`, the highcharts function cannot modify `LargeChartOptions` (because `options` is just a reference to that variable - yay Javascript)